# Query if a given tag or its description contains a word SE network wide

Tags: support, data-explorer

Is there a way to see or query if a given tag or a tags description contains a word across all SE sites?

Like the following meta-SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM all_tags_catalog 
WHERE tag like '%something%' OR tag_description '%something%'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following [cross-site query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/592704?search=%25database%25) does that for you.

Do note that the Tags table doesn't have an description or excerpt field. Almost all texts within the database are as much as possible stored in the posts table. That is why you'll find only two foreign-keys in the tags table, excerptpostid and wikipostid. To find the excerpt and wiki for a tag, we need to join with the posts table. The per database query would look like [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/592740):

```sql
select t.tagname
     , pe.body
     , pw.body
     , t.count
from tags t 
inner join posts pe on pe.id = t.excerptpostid
inner join posts pw on pw.id = t.wikipostid
where t.tagname like '%database%' collate sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_ai
or pe.body like '%database%' collate sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_ai
or pw.body like '%database%' collate sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_ai
```

To get the result for all sites within the Stack Exchange network you only need to run above query in each database which is what below script does:

```sql
declare @tagsearch nvarchar(200) = ##search:string##

-- result table, don't rename and keep the site column
create table #results ( site nvarchar(250)
                       , tagname nvarchar(35)
                       , excerpt nvarchar(max)
                       , wiki nvarchar(max)
                       , tagcount int);

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = ''   -- holds build up sql string

-- build one biq union sql, for each db
select @sql = @sql 
+ iif( len(@sql) > 1 
     , 'union'
     , 'insert into #results'
) +
-- here goes the per site query, fully qualify the database objects
N'
select ''' + name + '''
     , t.tagname
     , pe.body
     , pw.body
     , t.count
from ' + quotename(name) + '.dbo.tags t 
inner join ' + quotename(name) + '.dbo.posts pe on pe.id = t.excerptpostid
inner join ' + quotename(name) + '.dbo.posts pw on pw.id = t.wikipostid
where t.tagname like ''' + @tagsearch + ''' collate sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_ai
or pe.body like ''' + @tagsearch + ''' collate sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_ai
or pw.body like ''' + @tagsearch + ''' collate sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_ai
'
from sys.databases
where database_id > 5
-- and (name not like '%.Meta' or name = 'StackExchange.Meta')

--print @sql

-- execute it
exec (@sql)

-- show results
select
       -- URL builder from Lamak http://stackoverflow.com/a/38129701
      'http://' 
      + case PARSENAME(site,1)
        when 'audio' then 'avp'
        else PARSENAME(site,1)
        end 
      + coalesce('.' 
        + case PARSENAME(site,2)
          when 'audio' then 'avp'
          else PARSENAME(site,2)
          end , '')
      + IIF(patindex('%.MathOverflow%',site) > 0
      , ''
      , coalesce('.' + PARSENAME(site,3), '')
      )
      + IIF(patindex('%.MathOverflow%',site) > 0
      , '.net'
      , '.com'
      ) 
      + '/tags/'
      + tagname 
      + '|'
      + replace(site, 'stackexchange.','')
      -- rest of columns
      , tagname
      , excerpt
      , wiki
      , tagcount
from #results

drop table #results
```

When run today this can be the result when you search for %database%

[image: query result from search term database]

Comment: Did you seriously read this question *and* write this query in under two minutes?

Comment: @Glorfindel as it's known network wide, _rene_ is the ultimate SEDE warrior... however I miss freehand red circles to indicate where to look... _waters the flower_

Comment: Yes, I know that, but still, hats off. (We'll put on new hats soon, anyway.)

Comment: @Glorfindel I [cheated](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/34486455#34486455) but the tags table is in my [default template](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/508589/better-template-for-multi-db-queries) so it didn't need much work either.