# Using Data Explorer, how to get tag information for ALL Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: support, tags, data-explorer

Currently I am querying all tags available within a particular site using this query:

```
select
  t.tagName,
  e.body as 'Excerpt',
  w.body as 'WikiBody',
  Count
from tags t
left join Posts e
  on t.ExcerptPostId = e.Id
left join Posts w
  on t.WikiPostId = w.Id
order by t.tagName
```

However I have to run this individually for all sites (Stack Overflow, Ask Ubuntu, Stats etc) to get individual tag lists. How can I make a consolidated query which takes into account all 161 Stack Exchange sites?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible (I first thought the query would time out, but it didn't.) but SEDE queries are limited to 50,000 results. [Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/604614/list-of-all-tags-se-network-wide) is the query (which I forked over from @rene's answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/287908/295232)).

For reference, here is the complete query:

```sql
-- result table, don't rename and keep the site column
create table #results ( site nvarchar(250)
                       , tagname nvarchar(35)
                       , excerpt nvarchar(max)
                       , wiki nvarchar(max)
                       , tagcount int);

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = ''   -- holds build up sql string

-- build one biq union sql, for each db
select @sql = @sql 
+ iif( len(@sql) > 1 
     , 'union'
     , 'insert into #results'
) +
-- here goes the per site query, fully qualify the database objects
N'
select ''' + name + '''
     , t.tagname
     , pe.body
     , pw.body
     , t.count
from ' + quotename(name) + '.dbo.tags t 
inner join ' + quotename(name) + '.dbo.posts pe on pe.id = t.excerptpostid
inner join ' + quotename(name) + '.dbo.posts pw on pw.id = t.wikipostid
'
from sys.databases
where database_id > 5
-- and (name not like '%.Meta' or name = 'StackExchange.Meta')

--print @sql

-- execute it
exec (@sql)

-- show results
select
       -- URL builder from Lamak http://stackoverflow.com/a/38129701
      'http://' 
      + case PARSENAME(site,1)
        when 'audio' then 'avp'
        else PARSENAME(site,1)
        end 
      + coalesce('.' 
        + case PARSENAME(site,2)
          when 'audio' then 'avp'
          else PARSENAME(site,2)
          end , '')
      + IIF(patindex('%.MathOverflow%',site) > 0
      , ''
      , coalesce('.' + PARSENAME(site,3), '')
      )
      + IIF(patindex('%.MathOverflow%',site) > 0
      , '.net'
      , '.com'
      ) 
      + '/tags/'
      + tagname 
      + '|'
      + replace(site, 'stackexchange.','')
      -- rest of columns
      , tagname
      , excerpt
      , wiki
      , tagcount
from #results

drop table #results
```

Comment: amazing query! its sad though the results are limited to 50,000 records, so possibly this dataset might not contain all the tags. any other way to fetch all tags? maybe using [Stackexchange data dumps](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) ?

Comment: also I am curious how the query selected which rows to display within the 50k limit.

Comment: @KoustuvSinha feel free to [fork](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/fork/604614) it. The `#results` table will contain more than 50.000 rows, so you can probably play with the offset/limit.